# Unexpected negative delta datetime timestamps reason and possible solution

Tags: python, datetime, python-3.7

While computing the difference between time stamps I run into an unexpected behavior and I was wondering what is reason and the eventual fix.

From the code below, the latest result seems negative, while I was expecting `0:00:00.00000224000`

```py
import datetime
def delta_timestamps(d1, d2):
    d1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(d1, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %f")
    d2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(d2, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %f")
    return d1 - d2

print(delta_timestamps("2017-10-05 16:06:06 278001", "2017-10-05 16:06:06 278000"))
>>>0:00:00.000001
print(delta_timestamps("2017-10-05 16:06:06 278000", "2017-10-05 16:06:06 54000"))
>>> -1 day, 23:59:59.738000
```

Why is returning a negative value? How can we get the actual expected delta?

Comment: I think you should change the second `print` statement as follows: `print(delta_timestamps("2017-10-05 16:06:06 278000", "2017-10-05 16:06:06 054000"))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@dildelupbiten's suggestion worked, so before passing the values to `delta_timestamps` I filled microseconds part with leadings 0 (e.g. `milliseconds.zfill(6)`)

```py
def datetime_as_str_ms_formatting(s: str) -> str:
    s_splitted = s.split(" ")
    return " ".join(s_splitted[:2] +[s_splitted[2].zfill(6)])

print(delta_timestamps(datetime_as_str_ms_formatting("2017-10-05 16:06:06 278000"),
                       datetime_as_str_ms_formatting("2017-10-05 16:06:06 54000")))

>>> 0:00:00.224000
```